# System monitor tray

Tags: linux, system-monitor

More than 10 years ago, I built myself a panel including a.o. system monitor elements, based on [SuperKaramba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkaramba) (using Python), which I'm using up to now:

[image: Panel]
<sup>Panel with system monitor</sup>

Now I'm going to set up a fresh system (Linux Mint Cinnamon), and I don't want to drag all those KDE dependencies along just for that. I've been searching through Cinnamon applets for the panels up and down, but couldn't find what I'm after. True, there are monitors for CPU, memory, disks and network – but none fit my requirements. So what I'm looking for can either be separate applets to run in a panel, or a complete stand-alone panel including all of them (the latter must work right as a native panel does: always on top, reducing the screen size used by other apps).

Here are the details:

- **CPU:** graph as shown in the screenshot above, covering at least a minute, with the time frame preferably adjustable. One graph per CPU core, with the "real values" shown beneath.
- **Memory:** separate bar graphs for RAM and swap, with the full width representing available memory (i.e. 100%). Preferably coloring gradient from green (0%) via yellow (~60..75%) to red (~90%+), as the image shows for disks (see the one for `/home`). Uptime is a nice-to-have.
- **Disks:** similar to memory, but preferably show the remaining space in numbers. Same thing for the color gradient as described with *Memory.*
- **Network:** this should be a mixed graph for an interface one can configure. Like with memory and disks, a bar should show the current throughput – and like with CPU, a line graph has the "history" for the last minute (or a configurable interval). What makes 100% should be configurable: I want it to reflect my Internet traffic capabilities (e.g. whether a download/upload uses the full bandwidth available):
  [image: network]

Technical requirements:

- must run on Cinnamon. If it's agnostic to the desktop environment, all the better.
- should not carry too many dependencies. If it e.g. requires half of the KDE libs, I can as well stay with what I have.
- free and preferably open-source. I might consider other alternatives if I have to.
- as written initially, it can be an applet for Cinnamon, a collection of applets, or even a stand-alone panel acting like a native panel.
- in case of a stand-alone panel, additional elements are welcome if configurable. My current panel e.g. also holds a button to lock the screen and one to shutdown the system, a clock with date and time, and a "tray" for often used applications – all of those would be very welcome. As is the ability to plug in other third party applets :)